# I just want to check what is there any something wrong sentence in the following

Tags: american-english

I just want to check what is there any something wrong sentence in the following.

---

I'm looking for good opportunity to make grow up with my career.
so I'd like to apply to open position.

Comment: As it stands, this question is not a good fit for our site, since it's a very broad "proofread, please" request.  If you have any ideas of what might be wrong with it, you could identify those possible problems and ask specifically about them.

Comment: i got it,  but just once give me a break.

Comment: "make grow up with" is not idiomatic.  You want to say "advance". Also, "for an open position" and "a good opportunity".

Comment: I don't take it as a "proofread this" request. The OP is asking if his locutions are natural and correct, and it's only one sentence.

Comment: @Tim The length of the passage is not relevant to its categorization. The issue is that the result is not useful to anyone but the querant, and even then only useful in this moment. Even if this single sentence only has three errors, that means it could be posted as three questions, each focused on a particular grammatical issue. Then the answers would help the querant understand the aspect of English that led to the error and the site would increase in usefulness as an easily searchable repository of solutions to problems faced by English Language Learners.

Comment: I’ve written on the topic in more detail [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/can-i-write-a-paragraph-and-ask-for-corrections) and others have detailed similar viewpoints [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/669/can-i-ask-question-which-mainly-is-a-correcting-a-sentence) and [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/487/regarding-proofreading-questions). The middle link also demonstrates how Meta can be a good starting point for visitors who don’t know where they’ve erred. I’ll add that [ELL Chat](http://bit.ly/1rS0DKQ) can be good for this also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm looking for **a** good opportunity to **advance** my career, so I'd like to apply **to/for** **an** open position.

You need to add a couple of articles, and as @Tim Romano commented, *advance* is the correct term to use related to your career.